# Is it possible to set up IIS Administration API to work without access token?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

IIS Administration API requires access token to use. Context is that there is a number of servers where is should be accessible by a program with limited rights (hence api) and setting up tokens for each server individually can be tedious. So is there a way to configure it so it would skip authorization?

p.s. Wider context - a site is required to access a IIS binding list and have a map of site url and site folder.
p.p.s. I know that tokens and security are there for a reason.

Comment: _"and setting up tokens for each server individually can be tedious."_  - That sounds like you're doing server provisioning manually, which means you're doing something wrong - server machines are meant to be provisioned using tooling ("[cattle, not pets](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/653/what-is-the-definition-of-cattle-not-pets)").

Comment: @Dai, I'm talking about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis-administration/. It's a separate program (service)

Comment: Access tokens are an important security mechanism for authentication and authorization, ensuring that only authenticated and authorized users can access the API, and providing granular control over access permissions. Setting up the IIS management API to work without an access token is not a recommended practice as this will bypass its security mechanisms and may result in security risks.